# Regex for matching file suffix where filename contains multiple periods

Tags: regex, suffix, long-filenames

I am trying to match a series of suffixes, but, our file names often contain multiple periods for example *"Document A V0.1.1.docx"*

I have tried a number of solutions, but none seem to work for me and I'm not a great regex user... this is where I got to, but it fails to ignore multiple periods in the filename.

The regex will be used in the DocFetcher program to exclude large numbers of file from indexing where the suffixed filenames contents is of no use to the person using DocFetcher.

Suggestions?

```
(?i).*\.(jar|doc|docx|etc...)
```

Comment: Not used DocFetcher so do not know how it handles regex, but two things you can try (1) use `\.` to match the period (dot on its own means any char) (2) use `$` at the end to match the end of line

Comment: Thanks for that, simply adding $ at the end of the () list seems to have resolved the multi-period issue! '(?i).*\.(jar|doc|docx|etc...)$'

Comment: What do you want to match from the string above? Don't assume everyone know what DocFetcher is